# NextJS cannot find module constants.js on build

Tags: typescript, build, next.js, build-error

I have this error when running `next build` with `next` version `^10.2.3`.
I tried to delete `node_modules` and `.next` folder and fresh running `npm install && next build` without success.

```
  Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/shared/lib/constants.js'
  type: 'Error',
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '.next/server/pages/_document.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/build/worker.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js'
  ]
```

Comment: show package.json and see if constantsjs is part of dependecy

Comment: I had the same issue. The root cause was the root path of the netxjs project, a folder was named with a special character ('#' in my case on macos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear the npm cache by running the following command in your project's root directory:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Delete the package-lock.json file and the node_modules folder.

Reinstall the dependencies by running:

```
npm install
```

Restart your Next.js development server:

```
npm run dev
```

also remove the .next folder

Answer (score 10):

Try removing the `.next` folder and running again.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting the constants.js from package.json takes the problem away.